# Simple file read with Scala does not work

Tags: scala

Using Scala 2.10.2------------

I am a Java engineer, and started to learn Scala from yesterday, but I got stuck now, this simply code does not work for me, but when I use java to write it, it works fine:

```
    package lesson4

    import scala.io.Source
    import scala.reflect.io.File


    object Test {
        def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        var filePath = Source.getClass().getResource("/lesson4/test.txt")
        var file = Source.fromFile(filePath.getFile())
        var lines = file.getLines
        lines.foreach(println)
  }
}
```

The file is in the right path:
[image: path]
But the code just does not work:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/wenjiezhang/Desktop/source_files/git_hub%20workspace/Learning%20Scala/ScalaLearning/bin/lesson4/test.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at scala.io.Source$.fromFile(Source.scala:90)
    at scala.io.Source$.fromFile(Source.scala:75)
    at scala.io.Source$.fromFile(Source.scala:53)
    at lesson4.Test$.main(Test.scala:20)
    at lesson4.Test.main(Test.scala)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you can see from the error log, the path you're providing is being converted to a URL (for example `SPACE` becomes `%20`).  You should use the `fromURL` method `Source.fromURL(Source.getClass().getResource("/lesson4/test.txt"))`

[scala.io.Source docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.io.Source%24)

Comment: var filePath = Source.getClass().getResource("/lesson4/test.txt")
    var file = Source.fromURL(filePath)
    var lines = file.getLines
    lines.foreach(println).

Answer (score 2):

You have spaces in your path converted to encoded from the URL.